C#, Visual Studio 2022
Здраствуйте, проблема следующая.
При попытке открыть окно подключения к бд через Ado .NET Entity Model.
Выскакивает следующя ошибка.


Наверное, стоит дополнить вопрос.

А как его дополнить?

Я просто не понимаю что именно нужно сюда еще добавить. Ну еще перед етой ошибкой била другая связаная с доступом к реєстром или т.д.

Наверное есть логи студии, она в окне Output обычно пишет, что именно не так. Пока понятно только то что у вас возникла какая-то ошибка, а вот какая и почему - неизвестно. Скриншот никак не раскрывает эту тайну.

Нет ничего такого, Output пустой.

Уже перепробивал много идей с стека. Может есть другой способ подключить бд и создать CRUD?

если посмотреть ошибку в отладке, то стек трейс тоже пустой?

"Может есть другой способ подключить бд?" - можете попробовать EF Core, ADO.NET - страшная вещь
